# EditText language support?

Tags: android, unicode, android-edittext

My HTC Wildfire does not support Arabic and Hindi Unicode characters, however it supports Chinese. Arabic and Hindi characters are displayed as boxes. I have written an application that uses Google's translation service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is simply not supported yet. There are open bugs in the Android issues tracker: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1618 and http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5925. The latter has a comment by someone from Google at #15.

Comment: Sorry I don't have better news for you. My only suggestion is to star the two bugs to raise their importance.